# How to ensure .map completes before returning. (still getting my head around promises)

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

Why doesn't this log the object including the new values? What do I need to do so that it does?

If I wait a couple of seconds and then log(updateRepeaterData)the values are there.

```
async function setData() {
updateRepeaterData = await Promise.all(repeaterData.map(manimpulateData))
console.log(updateRepeaterData) //doesn't include new values
}

async function manimpulateData(itemSet) {
await doThis()
return itemSet

function doThis (){
  wixData.get("Goods", itemSet.goodMax)
    .then((results) => {
        itemSet.goodTitle = results.title
        itemSet.goodImage = results.image
  })}
}
```

As a side note I know I'm mixing await and promises, but for some reason if I use await as follows it does something to the array that throws the error

> error: The data parameter that is passed to the data method cannot be set to the value . It must be of type array.

```
async function doThis (){
let results = await wixData.get("Goods", itemSet.goodMax)
        itemSet.goodTitle = results.title
        itemSet.goodImage = results.image
}
```

[codesandbox of the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-ensure-map-completes-before-returning-still-getting-my-head-around-pro-fwkqe?file=/src/index.js) thanks to @hangindev

Comment: Where exactly does it throw that error?

Comment: The answers below are both correct, the source of my trouble (aside from not getting my promises right) was bad data, I didn't have anything in itemSet.goodMax for one of the items, so when it looped it didn't return one of the promises. Now the data is fixed the async method works fine.

Comment: Good, that would've been my guess given the error message :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `doThis` function. You are not returning a `Promise` in `doThis` that's why `await doThis()` doesn't work as expected.

To fix it, either add the `return` keyword:

```
function doThis() {
  return wixData.get("Goods", itemSet.goodMax).then((results) => {
    itemSet.goodTitle = results.title;
    itemSet.goodImage = results.image;
  });
}
```

or turn it to be an `async function`:

(like what you wrote in the question but you missed the `async` keyword which I believe is a typo)

```
async function doThis() {
  const results = await wixData.get("Goods", itemSet.goodMax);
  itemSet.goodTitle = results.title;
  itemSet.goodImage = results.image;
}
```

To be more concise, the `manimpulateData` function can be written as follow:

```
function manimpulateData(itemSet) {
  return wixData.get("Goods", itemSet.goodMax).then((results) => {
    itemSet.goodTitle = results.title;
    itemSet.goodImage = results.image;
    return itemSet;
  });
}
```

You may still encounter the error you mentioned as a side note but I believe it comes from elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks @Hangindev I've used your concise version, but it now doesn't log (I presume it hasn't returned all the promises) when I inspect updateRepeaterData is undefined

Comment: My bad. I edited `manimpulateData` function to return `itemSet`. Could your please try again?

Comment: Thanks but still not logging, still undefined.

Comment: Ok could you `console.log(results)` inside `then` block in `manimpulateData`?

Comment: I get a result from wixData.get for each item of the array (8 results)

Comment: Could you share one of the result? And what is `repeaterData`? I am working on this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-cherry-rz5pu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to recreate your scenario.

Comment: subtitle: "8 Weeks of Laughs"
image: "wix:image://v1/3cbab2_1f51037fa52d441394c8e54a2b247578~mv2.jpg/0ZN-fZOyV7c_Preview.jpg#originWidth=600&originHeight=424"
_id: "f6962041-fa5c-4a34-87c2-d37fc124fba5"
_owner: "3cbab2c9-a04d-4197-bbd6-68d6419dee7a"

Comment: ...as a sample, the whole thing is too long. repeaterData is an array of objects. Item set is just a random variable name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215880/discussion-between-hangindev-and-mrpowergage).

Answer (score 2):

You should make doThis promisified function. It's not waiting for the result from wixData.

```
async function manimpulateData(itemSet) {
    await doThis()
    return itemSet

    function doThis() {

        return wixData.get("Goods", itemSet.goodMax)
            .then((results) => {
                itemSet.goodTitle = results.title
                itemSet.goodImage = results.image
                return;
            })

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Hangindev's answer was correct. You don't need the `doThis` helper function at all though. Just write

```
async function manimpulateData(itemSet) {
    const results = await wixData.get("Goods", itemSet.goodMax);
    itemSet.goodTitle = results.title;
    itemSet.goodImage = results.image;
    return itemSet;
}
```

or (with `then` syntax)

```
function manimpulateData(itemSet) {
    return wixData.get("Goods", itemSet.goodMax).then(results => {
//  ^^^^^^
        itemSet.goodTitle = results.title;
        itemSet.goodImage = results.image;
        return itemSet;
//      ^^^^^^
    });
}
```